# WiringPi C++ serial function randomly stop working

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, wiringpi

When starting the GPS Ros Node the reading from the Raspberry Serial Port most of the time works but sometimes after rebooting, it does not read the data correctly and spills out the same char again and again(always a "?"). Only after recompiling or restarting the node, it starts working again.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int fd;

ros::init(argc, argv, "talker");

ros::NodeHandle n;

gps_node::gps_raw gps_data;

ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<gps_node::gps_raw>("gps_raw", 100);

ros::Rate loop_rate(1000);


if ((fd = serialOpen ("/dev/ttyAMA0", 115200)) < 0)
{
 fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open serial device: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
}

if (wiringPiSetup () == -1)
{
  fprintf (stdout, "Unable to start wiringPi: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
}
char input = 0;
while (ros::ok())
{
  while (serialDataAvail (fd))
  {
    input = serialGetchar (fd);
    ROS_INFO_STREAM(input);
        NazaDecoder.decode(input);
      gps_data.gps_sats = round(NazaDecoder.getNumSat());
    gps_data.lat = NazaDecoder.getLat();
    gps_data.lon = NazaDecoder.getLon();
    gps_data.heading = round(NazaDecoder.getHeadingNc());
    gps_data.alt = NazaDecoder.getGpsAlt();
    chatter_pub.publish(gps_data);
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that "?" isn't ROS not being able to display `(char)-1` as a character?  I don't know a lot about serial connections, but it seems reasonable that if one end dies you would need to close and re-open the link.

Comment: I'm currently not able to test it but I think that the normal, valid "char data stream" included "?" as well...

Comment: If you're reading GPS data I wouldn't expect it to be all printable characters.  You should really be logging the numeric representation of the bytes you receive.  That would likely give you more insight.  `serialGetchar` also returns an `int`, not a `char`.  Failure is represented by `-1`, which is indistinguishable from the (valid) byte `0xFF` if you immediately cast to `char`.

Comment: Sry for the late reply but yes indeed it's printing -1 (when using int) now when it's failing. But what can I do about it? Is a GOTO (to the beginning of the code) to reconnect a sufficient solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution, by reopening the serial port by failure.

```
if (wiringPiSetup () == -1)
  {
    fprintf (stdout, "Unable to start wiringPi: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
  }
  REINIT:if ((fd = serialOpen ("/dev/ttyAMA0", 115200)) < 0)
  {
   fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open serial device: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
  }

  int input = 0;
  while (ros::ok())
  {
    while (serialDataAvail (fd))
    {
      input = serialGetchar (fd);
        NazaDecoder.decode(input);
        gps_data.gps_sats = round(NazaDecoder.getNumSat());
      gps_data.lat = NazaDecoder.getLat();
      gps_data.lon = NazaDecoder.getLon();
      gps_data.heading = round(NazaDecoder.getHeadingNc());
      gps_data.alt = NazaDecoder.getGpsAlt();
      chatter_pub.publish(gps_data);
      ros::spinOnce();
      loop_rate.sleep();
      if(input==-1){
        goto REINIT;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
```